# PRESTASHOP 1.6 Add a category to a product programmatically

Tags: prestashop, categories, product, programmatically-created

In my module clients can add products to the shop, it will pass by a separate database.
When an admin check the products and validate one, i change the information to a prestashop product.

So i have this code :

```
$object = new Product();
$object->price = 32;
$object->id_tax_rules_group = 0;
$object->name = array((int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => $creation['title']);
$object->id_manufacturer = 0;
$object->id_supplier = 0;
$object->quantity = 1;
$object->minimal_quantity = 1;
$object->additional_shipping_cost = 0; 
$object->wholesale_price = 0;
$object->ecotax = 0;
$object->out_of_stock = 0;
$object->available_for_order = 1;
$object->show_price = 1;
$object->on_sale = 1;
$object->online_only = 1;
$object->meta_keywords = $creation['title'];
$object->active = 1;
$object->description_short = array((int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')) => $creation['description']);
$object->link_rewrite = array((int)(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT')) => $creation['title']); 

$object->id_category = 2;
$object->id_category_default = 2;
$object->addToCategories(array(2,13));

//SAVE
$object->save()
```

The product is saved and has the good information BUT it's not associated to any category.
When i go to my page products, where i can see all products, i see my product and the category is there BUT when i enter the details of the product and i go to the category list nothing is check.

i tried to see more in the code what is happenning and i saw this :

```
if (!in_array($new_id_categ, $current_categories))
    $product_cats[] = array(
    'id_category' => (int)$new_id_categ,
    'id_product' => (int)$this->id,
    'position' => (int)$new_categ_pos[$new_id_categ],
);
```

And after test the "if" is always true and so the product is association is never created.
I have check and this association does not exist.

I don't know what to do next, or if maybe i need to not use addToCategory, and enter maybe the data myself...

So please help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method addToCategories() assigns categories to already created product. In other words you need to call the save() method of the Product class before calling addToCategories();

Comment: I have already tried and faild that one, but i tried again and you are right, don't know what i missed the first time, but you just save me :) Thanks a lot